# Process terminated with status -1073741510 (Stack implementation using vectors in c++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a stack using vectors and i am getting a weird error in my code.
Its not letting me print anything else either. If i add another cout statement after it the command prompt window opens does nothing but display the error. I am not sure whats the problem with my code.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include "Stack.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main(){
    Stack a;
    a.push(2);
    a.push(100);
    a.printStack();

}
```

Header file for stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
class Stack
{
    vector<int> myStack;
    int top = 0;

    public:
        void push(int x);
        int pop();
        bool isEmpty();
        int length();
        void printStack();
};

#endif // STACK_H
```

Stack.cpp file for function implementations

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;


void Stack::push(int x){
    myStack[top] = x;
    top++;
}
int Stack::pop(){
    int r = myStack[top];
    myStack[top] = 0;
        top--;
    return r;
}
bool Stack::isEmpty(){
    return top== 0;
}
int Stack::length(){
    return top;
}
void Stack::printStack(){
    for(int x : myStack)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: And have you tried to debug this?

Comment: you never allocate memory. myStack.resize(myStack.size()+1) should appear in push

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) doesn't automatically resize when you use the `[]` operator. Consider calling through to `vector`'s `push_back` and `pop_back` methods.

Comment: [Potentially helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691954/native-exiting-with-with-code-1073741510-0xc000013a-while-using-prime-checke)

Comment: Can implement length() by doing myStack.size(), can imlement isEmpty() by doing return myStack.empty() or this.length() == 0;