# C: What is the cause of this -1073741819 (0xC000013A) error?

Tags: c

Running the below code in Code Blocks I am getting the error

> Process terminated with status -1073741510

I suspect that I am doing some mistake with the memory. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _point_ {
    int x_;
    int y_;
} point;

point* createPointOnHeap(int x, int y)
{
    point* my_point = malloc(sizeof(*my_point));
    if (my_point == NULL)
    {
      printf("Out of memory!\n");
      return NULL;
    }
    my_point -> x_ = x;
    my_point -> y_ = y;
    printf("x = %d \n", my_point -> x_);
    printf("y = %d \n", my_point -> y_);
    return my_point;
}

void givePointMemoryBackToHeap(point* my_point)
{
    free(my_point);
}

int main()
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 3;

  point* my_point = createPointOnHeap(x,y);
  givePointMemoryBackToHeap(my_point);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Below you see some screenshots where this occurs: I run the console application, but when I close the console (via the X button) the debugger shows said error.

[image]
[image].

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: That's not a compiler error. That's a runtime issue.

Comment: [Error 0xC000013A](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/31733/what-means-exit-code-0xc000013a-during.html) is explained there, and a related SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45691954/native-exiting-with-with-code-1073741510-0xc000013a-while-using-prime-checke).

Comment: Tip: when looking at error codes, also search them by their hexadecimal value `-1073741510` --> `0xC000013A`.

Comment: I don't see any error in this code. And no memory management error. Your allocation is just fine. And your free also. You are freeing only what you've allocated. The only problem is that if the malloc returns NULL, then you are still calling free, which would go wrong. You should test if `my_point` is NULL before calling `free` or `givePointMemoryBackToHeap` (depending on whether you test that in `main` or inside `givePointMemoryBackToHeap`). But that is obviously what went wrong here (it is unlikely that you have no memory left, and you would have seen the "Out of memory message")

Comment: Unrelated tip: the call to `printf("Out of memory!\n");` should be using `puts` as the string literal is not a format-string.

Comment: @chrslg I deleted my comment - I misread `malloc(sizeof(*my_point));` as `malloc(sizeof(point*));`. So did at least 2 other people judging by the now-deleted-answers already posted.

Comment: Works for me! Check environment.

Comment: OP, exactly **where** on your computer do you see "Process terminated with status -1073741510"? I'm not a CodeBlocks user, but I _suspect_ that CodeBlocks itself sends a Ctrl+C message to the debuggee, and in that case the message is benign...

Comment: @chrslg you can `free(NULL)` without harm. The C standard says *If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.*.

Comment: @Dai (so I deleted my answer to your comment). But the other did not misread the same way. In fact they did not misread. They assumed that it was wrong to use `*my_point` before the malloc is done. Which is obviously true generally speaking. But not when that `*my_point` is inside a `sizeof`, since in that case it is only a static code (no `*my_point` is really evaluated dynamically)

Comment: @WeatherVane According to cppreference, since C11 they say: _"The behavior is undefined if the value of ptr does not equal a value returned earlier by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, or `aligned_alloc()`"_ - so therefore _technically_ isn't calling `free(NULL)` UB if any previous call to `malloc` _didn't_ return `NULL`?

Comment: @Dai the C standard says *If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.* And since `malloc` can `return NULL` that's consistent.

Comment: @WeatherVane wasn't aware of that. But indeed, that is what man page says. Funny how I can still discover not so subtle and confidential things after decades of using `free`...

Comment: @Everybody: I made an edit to my post to better describe how the error occurs.

Comment: Posting images that are too small to read isn't really better. I compiled and ran your code error-free. But when I downloaded and expanded one image, the console says "Process returned 0".

Comment: @3nondatur So the error is not even from your code. Your code is already long terminated when that error occurs. It is an error from whatever environment provides a terminal emulator in windows so that you can use a console program. Probably a part of codeblocks itself. But whatever, it has nothing to do with anything in your code. Just with the fact that you are not closing your window correctly apparently in your environment. You would have the same problem with any code.

Comment: @3nondatur to be more accurate, it is said plainly in your screenshot: the process that have this error is `cb_console_runner.exe`. So, exactly as I said: an obvious module of codeblocks whose role is to provide a console. It executed your code. Your code terminated. Without any error, since you haven't any complain (it even says "process returned 0", which mean that it terminated without error). And say, long after that, because of the way you close that `cb_console_runner.exe` window, you got this error, because it seems that you are not supposed to close it with the `X`

Comment: @3nondatur btw, @WeatherVane else already pointed to a link about this error code that was apparently saying that (it was too specific to `codeblocks` to be of any significance to me, hence the continuing of the discussion. But turns out, it was the correct problem: just a codeblocks usage problem, not at all a C problem or anything related to your code. Again, that would have been the same with any C code)

Comment: @chrslg Methinks you should post your last 3 comments as the answer

Comment: @WeatherVane Re [Posting images that are too small to read isn't really better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76478062/c-what-is-the-cause-of-this-1073741819-error#comment134848606_76478062) -->I was able to get a legible picture once I clicked on the picture.